# Where does 2525 and 252525 come from in RSA cryptosystem example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, cryptography

This is an example from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

I understand how to encrypt, the first step is to turn the letters into their numerical equivalents(same thing we had to do for shift ciphers). The author's justification for grouping these numbers into blocks of four digits is that 2525 < 2537 < 252525.
I understand what n is. n in RSA is the product of two primes, 43 and 59 in this case. 
But why does n have to fall in the range of interval notation (2525, 252525)? Where do these two integers 2525 and 252525 come from?

Comment: Did you read the intro: "That is, we include an initial zero for the letters A through J, so that A is translated into 00,
B into 01, ... , and J into 09. Then, we concatenate these two-digit numbers into strings of digits. Next, we divide this string into equally sized blocks of 2N digits, where 2N is the largest even
number such that the number 2525 ... 25 with 2N digits does not exceed n. (When necessary, we pad the plaintext message with dummy Xs to make the last block the same size as all other
blocks.)"

Comment: Yeah understood the A - 00 idea. But even in that 2525 seemed arbitrary.

Comment: Encoding of messages can be done many ways, so you are correct. You can define your own, as long as both sides understand how to do it.

Comment: @Amzoti Do you know what 2N would be in this case?

Comment: Amzoti got it right. This is just one way of mapping "two letters" $\to$ "a single integer in the range $[0,2525]$". A less wasteful way of doing it would be to use base $26$. But your teacher apparently decided to do it this way for pedagogical reasons. Basically to avoid the need for the students to do several base conversions: base-10 $\to$ base-26 $\to$ base-10. The poinr is that such base conversions will divert the attention from the main point.

Answer (score 2):

Each letter generates two digits in the range $00-25$  Having selected the modulus $2537$ we cannot encrypt any number larger than that.  We note that the four digit codes coming from two letters cannot be larger than $2525$ and $2525 \lt 2537$, so we can encrypt any two letter pair at once.  Since a three letter set can generate a code of $252525$ and that is too large, we choose to encrypt letter pairs as the most efficient.  If we had chosen a product of primes in the range $252525-25252525$, it would make sense to encode letter triplets.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it comes from the encoding procedure of having A - 00, B - 01, ... , Z - 25.

Comment: Oh I see that 25 is the greatest distance from a. But why 2525 and 252525, not just 25?

Comment: You can use 25, but it will not be maximising the use of the large $n=2537$. It becomes a mono-alphabetic substitution cipher in that case (which can be easily broken with frequency analysis). Blocks of two letters make it harder.